# Is this MySQL Stored Procedure vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I have a MySQL stored procedure that uses Dynamic SQL. We went with Dynamic SQL because we have several tables with similar columns and we're trying to make the code as reusable as possible.

I'm concerned about SQL Injection, but standard attack strings don't seem to work on this. Is this stored procedure susceptible to SQL Injection? If so, is there a better way to write it?

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `sp_lookup`(IN tableName VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, name, FROM ', tableName, ' ORDER BY name');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedure won't add any additional security.

It does not prevent the SQL injection, you need to use prepared statement.

Another approach would be to use table white-listing, this means you first check that the table matches one of your existing tables if not do not run the query.

Comment: Upvoted as I was about to mention checking for a valid table name.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection can only occur when a user-supplied text string is concatenated into a SQL statement without adequate escaping. Since your table name is not going to be supplied by users, but by programmers, you're not in trouble.

You should however not do this. It is better for the database engine to have explicit statements, so they can be optimized correctly, and not have to re-parse the SQL on every call.

Comment: It is technically possible the programmers may just pass user input through, so it is a small concern.

Answer (score 0):

The table name should be surrounded by "ticks", and have any ticks escaped, like so:

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `sp_lookup`(IN tableName VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, name FROM `', REPLACE(tableName, '`', '\`'), '` ORDER BY name');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Despite currently lacking these, it seems your vulnerability would be fairly low; according to the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) "SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements"

Answer (score 0):

In isolation I would say that yes, this stored proc may be vulnerable, but that the vulnerability may not matter. What *does* matter is whether or not the value of the `tablename` parameter is coming from a trustworthy source.

If you examine one of your "standard attack strings," you'll see the attacker is attempting to complete your SQL query and then follow it with another query. In order to do this, the attacker has to be able to directly modify the string which is being spliced into your query.

If you use this SP in such a way that the value of `tablename` cannot be directly modified by a hostile user, then you do not have a SQL injection vulnerability.

I hope that made sense.